# DrRacket - update values in binary tree

Tags: racket

I'm writing a function which produces a new version of a binary tree `bt` where each Node whose value is an odd length string, has its value replaced with the string "odd". 
For example:

```
(check-expect (odd-length (make-node 4 "four"
                                     (make-node 7 "seven"
                                                empty
                                                (make-node 2 "two" empty empty))
                                     (make-node 32 "thirty-two" empty empty)))
              (make-node 4 "four"
                                     (make-node 7 "odd"
                                                empty
                                                (make-node 2 "odd" empty empty))
                                     (make-node 32 "thirty-two" empty empty))
```

I've managed to write a function that converts a single value, but I don't know how to make it work for all nodes in the binary tree. Can anyone help? Thanks a lot ><

```
(define-struct node (key val left right))
(define (change-str bt)
  (cond
    [(= (remainder (string-length (node-val bt)) 2) 1)
     (make-node (node-key bt) "odd" (node-left bt) (node-right bt))]
    [(= (remainder (string-length (node-val bt)) 2) 0) bt]))
```

Comment: you need to call it recursively on left and right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can simply define a `map` over trees and pass `change-str` as a function over `val`s.

```
(define (odd-length tree)
  (tree-map identity change-str tree))

(define (change-str str)
  (if (odd? (string-length str)) "odd" str))

(define (tree-map func-key func-val tree)
  (cond [(empty? tree) tree]
        [else (make-node (func-key (node-key tree))
                         (func-val (node-val tree))
                         (tree-map func-key func-val (node-left tree))
                         (tree-map func-key func-val  (node-right tree)))]))
```